# Get Azure FQDN (DNS Name) by Public IP Address

Tags: azure, powershell, dns, azure-powershell

To get the FQDN for the VM I can do it with -VMName like:

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -VMName "name"
$pubip = Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName | where{$_.Id -match $vm.Name}

$pubip.DnsSettings.Fqdn
```

But I want to do this with the local IP like (so no manual input neccessary):

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -IP "20.X.X.15"
```

Comment: It can be done using the Resource Graph. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511513/azure-graph-query-to-fetch-vm-name-and-private-ip-address

Comment: Hello @John_Doe, If the answer was helpful, Please  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***AFAIK, We can not use `IP address directly` to get the FQDN of Azure Vm, Firstly we need to retrieve the `PublicIP address` then after we can get the FQDN of the VM***.

As you are using the correct command above:-

[image]

For more information please refer this [***Blog***](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-azure-vm-dns-name-using-powershell) and as suggested @[***Ken W MSFT***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4800789/ken-w-msft) in comment.

Comment: $vm = Get-AzVM -VMname XXXXX
$pubip = Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName
$vm.ResourceGroupName | where{$_.Id -match $vm.Name }

$pubip.DnsSettings.Fqdn